# cocoa open a window two times

Tags: cocoa, window

If I close my app with the red x in the top left corner I can't reopen it. Why and how can I change this.

I want to open the windows after closing again and again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your window's behavior is checked "**release When Closed**" you need to uncheck it. Go to **Attributes Inspector**, here:

[image: Screenshot]

You didn't wrote how are you doing reopening window. So if You want to reopen window on dock icon click you can do it simply like this:

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)theApplication hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag
{
    if (flag) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        [windowOutlet orderFront:self];
        return YES;
    }   
}
```